# Why am I unable to see Application Insights events in my Azure Functions app?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a v4 .NET 6 functions app and I want to record custom Application Insights events.

I've added the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights` `3.0.30` NuGet package.

In Startup I've tried registering telemetry with

```
var telemetryConfiguration = new TelemetryConfiguration(VALID_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY_HERE);
builder.Services.AddSingleton(_ => new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration));
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(VALID_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY_HERE);
```

In my function I've wired up the `TelemetryClient` using constructor injection however when I check the instance in a break point there is no Instrumentation Key set?

I've also tried calling `TrackEvent` by newing up a TelemetryClient in my code but I'm not seeing the event in the Application Insights Logs view

```
new TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration(VALID_INSTRUMENTATION_KEY_HERE)).TrackEvent(new EventTelemetry("AddSearchesToQueue"));
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the `< PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="3.0.30" />` package reference in our .NET 6 Azure function project

And you need to initialize the **Custom Telemetry** in your function

The workaround below

**Funciton1.cs**

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run( [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post",Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(context.FunctionAppDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
    
    var connectionString = "ConnectionString";
    var tc = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient(new TelemetryConfiguration()
        { ConnectionString = config[$"{connectionString}"]  }
        );
    
    tc.TrackEvent("Calling azure function", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "FunctionType", "Function action" } }, null);
    tc.TrackEvent("Processing task item", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Item", "Your item" } }, null);
    tc.TrackEvent("Completed azure function");
    
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    
    string name = req.Query["name"];
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.": $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
    
    tc.TrackEvent("Responsemessage:" + responseMessage);
    tc.Flush();
    
    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    
}
```

**Local.settings.json**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": { 
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "<App insights instrumentation key>",
        "ConnectionString": "<Your Connection stirng for app insghts>"
    }
}
```

[image]

I could see the **custom logs** in Application insights

[image]

Refer [Tracing and logging with Application Insights](https://dzimchuk.net/tracing-and-logging-with-application-insights/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first go, this may feel out of context but this is what happened with me. My **code was absolutely correct** but the issue was that my Application Insights was connected to an Azure Log Analytics Workspace which had so many other App Insights connected to it so there was huge amount of data getting ingested into it. And, there was a **Daily cap** of 5 GB put **on the Log Analytics Workspace**.

So, **even if your code is correct but there is any restriction on the Log Analytics Workspace, you will not receive any error and your code will work seamlessly but no traces, information, error, events etc. will be visible in your Application Insights.**

It is advisable to check if there are any such setting enabled at the App Insights or Log Analytics Workspace. Another thing that can be check is Network Isolation which sometimes blocks telemetry from public sources if Virtual network access configuration section has a **Yes** for both the options.